# How can I validate format date in Map request body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

How can I pass date with pattern in a map request body ?

my request body:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "dateAt": "2018-06-08"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "dateAt": "2018-06-09"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Controller:

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> getInfo(@Valid @RequestBody Map<String, List<RequestDTO>> requestDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {
// code here
}
```

My request:

```
public class RequestDTO {
private long id;
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dateAt;
//getter, setter
}
```

if I chagne data type of dateAt into String, it runs well. I change the data type into java.util.Date, it does not work - return http status is 400. Anyone know ?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Send `dateAt` value as long instead of formatted text

Comment: Please use java date deserializer

Comment: try with @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne already, it does not work

Comment: @Rcordoval it does not work as well

Comment: Please refer this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713285/gsonbuilder-serializer-mess-up-with-timestamp-and-date/50713662#50713662

Comment: if this is still an issue, a detailed stack trace would help. Its needs to be figured out if its a deserialization problem or request validation problem. I have a similar code & it works.